# Logo Critique: Which version elicits the intended reaction?

Tags: logo, critique

This logo is for an upscale startup veterinary clinic.

Considering both the typography and the image, which version of the logo conveys message of **memorable, friendly, yet upscale**?

Color has yet to be added - narrowing down typography class and image style first. Typography and images will be tweaked later, as well as color added.

[image: veterinary clinic logo]

Comment: Please edit your post to follow GD.SE's [critique requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682).

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for your question. Could you [edit] your question further to elaborate on what exact aspect of the logo you are struggling with? As it stands now it is little more than a popularity poll.

Answer (score 1):

In B the picture looks like it's missing a flag to which the cat and dog can look up while saying their pledge.

The fonts are kinda "meh" for an upscale establishment. B is too cold and stern. A looks like budget brand of some more prestigious one (Think felix from Purina).

I would advise to use "soft" friendly picture from A and clash it with some serif font. that way you will get the friendliness and smoothnes from picture with proffesionalism and experience from font without "coldness" of sans-serif.

Side note: I don't know if this is  render issue but the cat in A look like it have a pointy nose. When cats put ears  like in the picture they tend to tilt their head making their nose point down. https://pl.depositphotos.com/303043844/stock-photo-side-view-of-curious-cat.html?ref=26681138

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my personal opinions and what I would like as a logo if I had my own clinic. I don't have any *scientific* explanations, but this is what I feel.

I prefer **option B** for following reasons:

1. The animal is looking towards sky and in *positive* direction. Similarly, they are *looking* towards the name of clinic/organization. Which makes me feel like animals do have hope because someone (clinic) is there to care for them. Similarly
2. There are 2 animals sitting together observing same thing. Which creates a feeling of friendliness. Don't want to say that two faces looking in opposite directions (like option A) can't create friendliness, but I find B easy to perceive such feeling.
3. For above 2 reasons, I find it a bit more memorable
4. I would use the curved font style (option A) for a restaurant maybe.
5. The font in B looks a bit more professional to me for this kind of service.

Overall, option A looks more beautiful to me, but I would choose option B for the opinions shared above.

Answer (score 0):

I think B is better. On the other hand, I like the picture of option A more. In Option B, the fonts are more professional, more formal, better. A-reminiscent of more "amusement park" logo fonts. However, the picture of Option A is ingenious.

Comment: I think A is better all round, it seems friendlier, like a place where people are nice to animals. B looks too formal. Context is important to me here: that building doesn't look friendly, it feels like a place where animals are slaughtered not looked after. It needs all the help it can get to make it look friendly. Maybe some murals or a paint job would help, besides the logo.

Comment: @Copilot For a kennel or similar, I’d agree. For a _hospital_, where you’re looking for skilled surgeons and expert veterinarians, formal would definitely be what I’d be looking for over friendly. Yes, you want your animal looked after with kindness, but skilled, professional staff would be more important to me if I were taking an animal in for surgery.